# Programmatically set identity on WCF EndpointAddress

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, basichttpbinding

I am using the following function to create a `System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress` when connecting to a WCF Service:

```
private static EndpointAddress GetEndPointAddress(string url, EndpointIdentity identity)
{
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri(url);
    EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(
        baseAddress,
        identity,
        new AddressHeaderCollection());
    return endpointAddress;
}
```

I need to pass in an `EndPointIdentity` that correlates with the following excerpt from my web.config:

```
<identity>
  <dns value="Some Value" />
</identity>
```

My WCF Service uses an X509 certificate, so it seems that my identity needs to be of type `X509CertificateEndpointIdentity`. The constructor for this requires me to pass in a certificate...but I want to pass it a dns value, as shown above.

Can anyone suggest what is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact I needed to create a DnsEndpointIdentity, as follows:

```
DnsEndpointIdentity identity = new DnsEndpointIdentity("Some value");
```