# This two codes should be equivalent? Setting Endpoint programmatically

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm consuming a WCF service not made by my company.

I need to have my WCF settings in code (no `.config` file modification).

With that in mind I'm trying to use a method in a plain Project with the settings in `Web.config` (generated by `Add Service Reference`) to test first. It does work.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IIntegracao" />
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://wcf.mydomain.com.br/Integracao.svc/Integracao.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IIntegracao"
            contract="ServiceReference1.IIntegracao" name="WSHttpBinding_IIntegracao">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="user@mydomain.com.br" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And I'm calling it like this:

```
using (var client = new ServiceReference1.IntegracaoClient())
{
    var resultado = client.Incluir(new Inclusao());
}
```

I continue my task removing all settings from `Web.config` and could'nt manage to make it work.

I even tried to leave the `Web.config` untouched and just inform it in the client constructor like this:

```
string url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["same url as above"];

var client2 = new IntegracaoClient(
            "WSHttpBinding_IIntegracao",
            new EndpointAddress(url));

var resultado2 = client2.Incluir(new Inclusao());
```

Didn't work

> System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException was
>   unhandled   HResult=-2146233087   Message=SOAP security negotiation
>   with 'http://wcf.mydomain.com.br/Integracao.svc/Integracao.svc' for
>   target
>   'http://wcf.mydomain.com.br/Integracao.svc/Integracao.svc'
>   failed. See inner exception for more details.
>
> InnerException: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
>          HResult=-2147467259
>          Message=Security Support Provider Interface (SSPI) authentication failed. The server may not be running in an account
>   with identity 'host/wcf.mydomain.com.br'. If the server is running in
>   a service account (Network Service for example), specify the account's
>   ServicePrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for the
>   server. If the server is running in a user account, specify the
>   account's UserPrincipalName as the identity in the EndpointAddress for
>   the server.
>          Source=System.ServiceModel

My question is: Is the second call equivalent to the first one?

AS I understand the second call says to the client to use the same configuration used in the first call. Why does the second fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equiivalent. In config you set the endpoint identity to some user, in code you don't do that.

```
ServiceEndpoint ep = myServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
                typeof(ICalculator),
                new WSHttpBinding(),
                String.Empty);
EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:8088/calc"),
     EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("contoso.com"));
ep.Address = myEndpointAdd;
```

Take a look at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628618.aspx
[Programmatically set identity on WCF EndpointAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798684/programmatically-set-identity-on-wcf-endpointaddress)

Comment: Interesting that the Indetity is in the config but in the constructor is jst in the Address.

Comment: I couldn't find a constructor taking just Uri and Identity so I elaborate beyond your anwer and managed the correct result for me.

Answer (score 0):

After `@Jocke` posted hist answer I elaborate more and could find the solution.

Like he said the configuration has *Identity* in the `config` but when setting in the code it is the address that should take care of it.

Since I couldn't find the same constructor as he said I needed some changes to make it apropriate for my code (Framework 4):

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(
    new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["same url as above"]),
    EndpointIdentity.CreateUpnIdentity("user@domain.com.br"),
    (System.ServiceModel.Channels.AddressHeaderCollection)null);

var client3 = new ServiceReference1.IntegracaoClient(
    new WSHttpBinding(),
    endpoint);
```

This last constructor parameter casting `null` is just to clarify to the compiler whitch overload I wanted. And I used `CreateUpnIdentity` instead.